# Modify the POST header

Tags: java

The XML-RPC server I am trying to communicate with requires that each request contains the following in the first line of the HTTP header:

```
POST /Air HTTP/1.1
```

however the following code we used,

```
urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlc.setConnectTimeout(180000);
urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "AVAYA/3.1/1.0");
urlc.addRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic QXZheWE6QXZheWE=");
urlc.addRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
urlc.setDoOutput(true);
urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

which results in....

```
POST HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Avaya/3.1/1.0
Authorization: Basic QXZheWE6QXZheWE=
Content-type: text/xml
```

i.e. without the "/Air" bit.

Please help us in modifying the POST header

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with what you're trying to do, but I have the feeling that using HTTPURLConnection will not suit your needs.  Consider using Apache HTTPClient. Good luck.

Comment: @SteveP. There is absolutely no reason the standard Java `HttpURLConnection` can not be used for a simple HTTP `POST` operation. All that's required is, you know, an actual URL to post to ...

Comment: @BrianRoach I understand that.  I wasn't sure if you could modify the POST HTTP/1.1 through Java HttpURLConnection.  Apparently, I guess you can.

Comment: It wouldn't be very good at HTTP if you couldn't specify an URL ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "/Air" part is included in your url. Currently it's not.